# Async Waterfall function only call the first callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to play a bit with node and async waterfall function. This is my code:

```
var async = require('async');

var waterfall = function (req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        _function1(req),
        _function2,
        _function3
    ], function (error, success) {
        if (error) { alert('Something is wrong!'); }
        console.log("success");
        return alert('Done!');
    });
};

function _function1 (req) {
    return function (callback) {
        var something = req.body;
        console.log("first");
        callback (null, something);
   }
}

function _function2 (something, callback) {
    return function (callback) {
      console.log("second");
       var somethingelse = function () {  };
       callback (err, somethingelse);
    }
}

function _function3 (something, callback) {
    return function (callback) {
      console.log("third");
      var somethingmore = function () { };
      callback (err, somethingmore);
    }
}

waterfall(function(){}, function(){});
```

But in the output I get only 'first'. Why another callbacks are not called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return a function from `_function2` and `_function3`. The reason it's being done for `_function1` is to pass `req` in (which can be done in better ways, see below):

```
function _function2 (something, callback) {
  console.log("second");
  var somethingelse = function () {  };
  callback (err, somethingelse);
}

function _function3 (something, callback) {
  console.log("third");
  var somethingmore = function () { };
  callback (err, somethingmore);
}
```

To get `req` into the waterfall, you could use this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) { return callback(null, req); },
    _function1,
    _function2,
    _function3
], ...);
```

Or (which I would prefer):

```
async.waterfall([
    _function1.bind(this, req),
    _function2,
    _function3
], ...);
```

In both cases, you wouldn't need to return a function from `_function1` either:

```
function _function1 (req, callback) {
  var something = req.body;
  console.log("first");
  callback (null, something);
}
```